# How to unselect button after switch betweens two components with different routes?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, router

I have home page, which have 3 nav buttons:

- "Team" button
- "All" button
- "Individual" button

That are navigation buttons they will redirect user, "Team" and "All" buttons redirect user on **same** Component but **different roots**.

When "Team" btn is clicked user is redirect on root '/' and "Team" btn is selected. That is ok.

> This is problem:
>
> When user click "All" btn, btn is selected. But "Team" btn is still
>   selected.
>
> Problem is cus that are two diff routes same component.

I set `activeRouteAll: true` when user click on All buttons:

```
if (route === '/all') {
      return <IntakeSupervisorAnalytics  userRole={userRole} activeRouteAll={true} />
 }
```

This is array of buttons:

```
let navigationButtons = [
      {
        content: 'Team View',
        onClick: () => runtime.navTo('/'),
        style: {
          // this is background-co when btn is active: '#BABBBC'
          backgroundColor: activeRouteAll ? '#E0E1E2bbb5b5' : '#BABBBC'
        }
      },
      {
        content: 'All',
        onClick: () => runtime.navTo('/all'),
        style: {
           // this is background when btn is active: '#BABBBC'
          backgroundColor: activeRouteAll ? '#BABBBC' : '#E0E1E2bbb5b5',
        }
      },
      {
        content: 'Individual View',
        onClick: () => runtime.navTo('/analytics'),
        style: { backgroundColor: '#E0E1E2bbb5b5' }
      }
    ]
```

**step 1:** I am on Team View page and team view btn have background which make him active

**step 2.** Click on All btn and "Team View" btn needs without that background style which previously he get.

How to active that?

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for **activeRouteAll** to set the background, but you should check for the current location and depending on this you can set the background. Try to use   **this.props.location**

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location